# Exibir DataTable só se houver registro

Tags: java, jsf

Eu possuo vários datatables em um painel, cada um exibe um valor de um objeto e um botão, e conforme o dado é recebido, alguns são preenchidos e outros não, o problema é que esses que não tem registro ele ainda aparece o botão, tem como fazer pra ele não aparecer, ou só ficar um "sem registro",

Comment: Como não está clara ? Nem toda dúvida tem que ter código! Estou a procura de um componente que eu não conheço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia por exemplo setar o "visible" do botao logo após "preencher" as tables. Caso o rowCount de 0 então seta o visible do botão como false.

Ou se quiser é só mudar o nome do botão para "Sem Registro"(como foi uma de suas ideias) atravéz da propriedade setTitle do botão.

Comment: Deu certo, fiz variáveis booleanas, e no disabled no command button eu faço a condição em cima dessa variáveis